# Add new Action to a existing Magento route - Magento2

Tags: magento2, controllers

Here is my scenario, I want to add a new Action to an existing Magento route, for example under the MyAccount section you can find /sales/order/[view, history, etc]; I want to add an index like an Order section dashboard.

I tried to implement this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34908125/magento-2-controller-post-throwing-404-error
without luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, you need to create a custom extension with the following file structure (for example adding new action to checkout/cart/):

[image: Add action extension structure.]

We need the following files to make it work:

1) **registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Amasty_Checkout',
    __DIR__
);
```

2) **composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "amasty/checkout",
    "description": "Amasty Test",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "amasty/base": "*"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "license": [
        "Commercial"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Amasty\\Checkout\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

3) **module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Amasty_Checkout" schema_version="1.0.0" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

4) **routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="checkout">
            <module name="Amasty_Checkout" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

5) **Test.php** (adding /test/ action)

```
<?php
namespace Amasty\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Test extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add
{

    public function execute()
    {
        die('asdasdasd');
    }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Test action result.]

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. I didn't have time to check the fix yet. I'll let you now how was

Comment: @Amasty, I want to add new custom tab for customer account.Could you please guide how I can do this?

Comment: @Amasty in `routes.xml` file you have to specify only `id` attribute of `route` node, and you are strongly advised to use a `before` or `after` tag's attribute to control the order Magento will check for matches in, to avoid accidental overrides of existing core controllers